# Performing Vlookup from different workbook

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am trying to do a vlookup using VBA. The reference data is in another workbook.
I was thinking to assign a variable for the data workbook & worksheet, but wasn't able to make it work. The sub runs, but does not return any result in the desired worksheet.

**WbVlookup** is the variable for vlookup data workbook
**BuildplanRange** is the variable for vlookup data range
The code needs to run from Row 14 to the last result row

It seems to me the variable wasn't assigned correctly for both workbook and datarange, but I wasn't able to figure out what was wrong.

```vb
Sub VlookupForColumnGHIJ()

Dim EndofRow As Long
Dim RowX As Integer
Dim WbVlookup As Workbook
Dim BuildplanRange As Range

Set WbVlookup = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\DengSilin\Downloads\Copy of 98289 (FL512S)_Allocation File_WW18 (002)_Cindy_02022021.xlsx")
Set BuilPlanRange = WbVlookup.Worksheets("Build Plan").Column("F:I")

EndofRow = Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For RowX = 14 To EndofRow
    Cells(RowX, 6) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(RowX, 3), BuilPlanRange, 2, 0)
Next RowX

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is making an assumption about which workbook is `Active`. My suggestion is to create a habit to ALWAYS fully reference your workbooks and worksheets, it saves lots of time chasing errors.

So your code starts with

```
Dim WbVlookup As Workbook
Dim BuildplanRange As Range
Set WbVlookup = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\DengSilin\Downloads\Copy of 98289 (FL512S)_Allocation File_WW18 (002)_Cindy_02022021.xlsx")
Set BuilPlanRange = WbVlookup.Worksheets("Build Plan").Column("F:I")
```

which is very explicit and clear. But next, you are referencing `Cells`:

```
EndofRow = Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

The `Cells` in this case reference the current `ActiveWorkbook` by default. Because you've just opened the `WbVlookup` workbook, this is very likely your active workbook. I'm guessing this is not what you want.

So a quick change to this may work

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set wb = Thisworkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("IwantThisSheet")

Dim EndofRow As Long
With ws
    EndofRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For RowX = 14 To EndofRow
        .Cells(RowX, 6) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Cells(RowX, 3), _
                                                             BuilPlanRange, 2, 0)
    Next RowX
End With
```

Comment: Oh my god it works! I've been struggling for the whole afternoon yesterday trying to figure out why it doesn't work! Thanks, I should have seek for help earlier